# Options for setting up podcast syndication on an Android device

Tags: podcast

On an Android device, what options do I have for following podcasts via web syndication our other forms of syndication? How do I set up syndication of podcasts on an Android device, and, since the files are downloaded automatically to my device, what options do I have to control download versus streaming, and are old episodes of the podcasts automatically deleted? Otherwise, do I need to have much blank space on the device to user it? I side it depends on the length of the podcasts.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: You're overthinking this, and off-loading some of the thinking to us. Your knowledge of the different types of podcasting lends well to your experimentation. The app itself is the governor of what needs to be streamed vs. downloaded, player styles and actions, and deletions, when necessary. Find the tool you like best, of the many out there. My only addition as a requirement is the need for OPML import, as a must. This way, if you want to move on, you won't need to re-type all the subscriptions you have into a new tool.

Comment: Interesting. I see the OPML format is used to exchange two feeds between two aggregators. That way, if I change mismatched, I can export and import playlists of podcast stations from one to the other, off-road even saving the OPML list in the cloud, an I correct?

Comment: You are correct, but again, the tools themselves say what and where. Local is good enough for what amounts to a once-and-done operation. There's no saying you can't use cloud, though. If cloud is your requirement, find the tool that makes it an option.